# Handle ping outputs

Tags: networking, ping

I using 'shell_exec' function in php to ping an address and I wanted to know what are the possible results so I could handle them. What I did is to try to get with regular expression the loss percentage.

- If loss = 100, **I print "Transmit failed. General failure".**
- if loss = 0, **I print the approximate round trip times in milli-seconds**
- if regular expression fails to find loss percentage **I print ping request could not find host X. Please check the name and try again.**

What else could be the result?

Comment: What platform are you running on.  Different versions of ping on different OS and OS versions may have very different output.

Comment: The version of `ping` would also be useful. `ping -V` on my Linux box.